# Selenium WebDriver - Ruby, PageFactory, PageObject

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

im beginner in WebDriver. But I have question, becouse i cant find it in the internet. Is in ruby something like PageFactory, PageObiect?
Where can I find tutorials?

Comment: Is this the kind of thing you're looking for? https://github.com/Ladtech/page_magic

Answer (score 1):

There is a [page-object](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object) gem examples and docs you can find on github